# How to hyperlink the text of a div class using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am developing an HTML weather application. It collects data from Yahoo Weather API. It can get the detailed Yahoo report's link from the API. The ".city" div class contains only one text, the name of the city using this code in JavaScript:

```
$(".city").text(localStorage.typhoon_location || weather.city)
```

How do I add a hyperlink to the text using JavaScript? Let's assume that the hyperlinked information is counted as `weather.link`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<s>You can add click handler like</s>

```
//Add data
$(".city").data("weather-link", weather.link);

//Add click handle
$(".city").on('click', function(){
    //do something
    window.location.href = $(this).data("weather-link");
})
```

### EDIT

Use

```
$('.city').html(
  '<a href="' + localStorage.typhoon_link + '">' + localStorage.typhoon_location + '</a>'
  || '<a href="' + weather.link + '">' + weather.city + '</a>')
```

Comment: This makes the whole frameless webkit window turn into the website. I have already made the code that when any <a> class is clicked, It will open a link in an external window. How to add some <a href=""></a> in the city div class?

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi, Have you tried `$('.city').html(
      '<a href="' + localStorage.typhoon_link + '">' + localStorage.typhoon_location + '</a>'
      || '<a href="' + weather.link + '">' + weather.city + '</a>')`

Comment: This works, the other answer had `$('.city').text` which did not work.   I have a question to you. I posted this question in  programmers.stackexchange.com from which it was migrated here. Where should I ask questions related to programming?

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi, great :) Post question here, that site is for **interested in conceptual questions**

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer to you less DOM manipulation as possible:

```
$('.city').text(
  '<a href="' + localStorage.typhoon_link + '">' + localStorage.typhoon_location + '</a>'
  || '<a href="' + weather.link + '">' + weather.city + '</a>')
```

This way you can control if you want to open it in tab or new window, not replacing `window.location.href`...

Comment: It should be `$('.city').html(....)` or it makes all `<a href.......</a>` turn into text.